# Do i need to buy a new digital certificate for my Synology NAS?

Tags: security, vpn, nas, ssl, certificate

I have a Synology NAS at home. I have installed the VPN Server package and enabled Open VPN.

There is a default digital certificate provided by Synology installed on it. From a security point of view, Should I buy a new certificate and replace this one or is it OK to use the existing one? I guess my question is, is this certificate installed on every Synology NAS or is it unique for each.

If it is going to be the same then isn't it a security issue? because I can decrypt any content that has been signed by by this certificate from any Synology NAS? Especially if I want to expose this on the internet?

Do i need to buy a new digital certificate for my NAS? Or is it enough/ok to use the default certificate that Synology provides with the NAS?

Comment: A self-signed certificate should be enough in a case like this.  Realistically there is no difference between a digital certificate you purchase which is signed by a Root Certificate Authority you trust and a certificate you signed yourself (one has to presume you trust yourself).   However, only you can decide, if you actually need a certificate signed by Root Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 2):

They are self signed certificates that are likely sufficient for what you're doing. You can also easily generate a new one. Whenever you deem it secure is up to you.

If you want to buy official certificates you will have to look at what those certificates require in order to be usable for your VPN (usually some kind of client authentication) and make sure to buy the correct one. Lots of certificates that are easily obtainable are probably restricted to web servers.

Comment: So it is different certificate for each Synology NAS?

Comment: They might start out with the same certificates but at least after generating a new one you will have a unique one - unless they do something very stupid. You can manually check the certificate and have a look at its properties.

Comment: It should be a unique certificate generated and signed by Synology.  You can of course confirm this is the case.